# PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (stdin:8: attempt to call global 'run' (a nil value))

Tags: lua, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

Using NodeMCU from https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware running the following code:

```
ssid = "www.mydomain.com"
pass = "234234234432"


gpio.write(0, gpio.LOW)

print("Startup up wifi mode")

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(ssid, pass)

wifi.sta.autoconnect(1)
wifi.sta.connect()


tmr.alarm(3, 1000, 1, function() 
    if (wifi.sta.status() < 5) then
        print("Connecting...")        
    else 
        tmr.stop(3)
        print("Connected having IP "..wifi.sta.getip())
        gpio.write(0, gpio.HIGH)        
        run()      
    end
end)

gpio.write(0, gpio.HIGH)




function run() 
    print("run")

    myhost="www.adafruit.com"
    mypage="testwifi/index.html"
    myip=""

    sk=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
    sk:dns(myhost,function(conn,ip) 
    myip=ip
    sk=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
    sk:on("receive", function(sck, c) print(c) end )
    sk:connect(80,myip)
    sk:send("GET / " .. mypage .." HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " .. myhost .."\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")
    sk=nil


end
```

I got this error:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (stdin:8: attempt to call global 'run' (a nil value))
����m������!������!�1���
Waiting answer from ESP - Timeout reached. Command aborted.
```

**How do I resolve this?**

Comment: Move the `run()` function definition above the `tmr.alarm()` call?!

Comment: Please write an answer so I can accept it and explain why this is important.

Comment: What does this output mean ``����m������!������!�1���``? Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that NodeMCU/Lua is fully asynchronous and that functions need to be defined before they're invoked.

```
function start()
  tmr.alarm(3, 1000, 1, function() 
      if (wifi.sta.status() < 5) then
          print("Connecting...")        
      else 
          tmr.stop(3)
          print("Connected having IP "..wifi.sta.getip())
          gpio.write(0, gpio.HIGH)        
          run()      
      end
  end)

  gpio.write(0, gpio.HIGH)
end

function run() 
    print("run")

    myhost="www.adafruit.com"
    mypage="testwifi/index.html"
    myip=""

    sk=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
    sk:dns(myhost,function(conn,ip) 
    myip=ip
    sk=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
    sk:on("receive", function(sck, c) print(c) end )
    sk:connect(80,myip)
    sk:send("GET / " .. mypage .." HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " .. myhost .."\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")
    sk=nil
end

start()
```

Also, consider what happens if your device looses connection to the WiFi *after* it connected successfully. You stopped the timer...

Comment: What should I do when wifi connection is lost?

Comment: You could keep a "global" connected variable and a timer that is never stopped which monitors this. Example: https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/63ce6e6d78cef435d2ec

Comment: What does this output mean ����m������!������!�1���? Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I believe that's simply due to different baud rates the ESP temporarily communicates at.